# why python saves graph partially in high dpi?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dpi, highdpi, savefig

I need to save a graph with high resolution by:

```
plt.savefig('trace', format='jpeg', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=3000)
```

The main graph is:
[image]

But it saves partially, like this:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example where this happens?  For instance we don't know how big the original figure is.  In general Matplotlib is limited to 2**16 = 65,536 pixels in each direction so if your figure is more than 21.8 inches long it will have problems. (though if that were the problem I'm surprised is saved anything at all)

Comment: Here the main image is just a screen shot because I couldn't save it. But the one that has been saved partially is 11.6 Mb. Also, I have used: ` f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(14)
f.set_figheight(4) `  for the dimensions.

Comment: My guess is you are hitting some sort of limit in the underlying libraries and will have to reduce the dpi or make the figure smaller.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I made the figure smaller but with the same dpi. Now, it works.